# Selecting data from schema based table in Postgresql using psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I'm a newbie in Python and would like to select some data from postgreSQL database using python psycopg2 API.

The table I'm selecting is inside a schema dl(dl.products),so when I write the code

```
Conn=   psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database="postgres",user="postgres", password="postgres")
  Cur=conn.cursor()
  Cur.execute("select * from dl.products")
```

It's showing the error **relation dl.products  doesn't exists**.

Can anyone show me an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the below code,

```
  Query = """select * from dl."products";"""
   cursor.execute(Query)
   print("Selecting rows from test table using cursor.fetchall")
   row = cursor.fetchone()
   while row is not None:
        print(row)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
   print("Print each row and it's columns values")
```