# Query data from schema.table in Postgres

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm very new to sqlalchemy and I encountered a problem regards to Postgres databases. I can successfully connect to the postgresql database, and I think I've directed the engine to my desired schema.

```
cstr = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@{server}:{port}/{database}"
engine = create_engine(cstr,connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format("schema_name")},echo=True)
con = engine.connect()

print(con.execute('SELECT * FROM table_name'))
```

This prints out the correct schema_name.

```
insp = inspect(con)
print(insp.default_schema_name)
```

However, I still get error messages saying that the table does not exist.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "table_name" does not exist
```

---

I also tried without the `,connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format("google")}` clause and use `schema_name.table_name` in the sql query. Same error occurs. It's not a local database, so I can't do anything to the database except getting data from it. What should I do here？

Comment: Is `table_name` actually a mixed case / upper case name?

Comment: it doesn't matter in my case.

Comment: So the table has been created using a regular identifier, not a delimited identifier? Your comment seems to hint at the former, but your answer hints at the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's interesting how I searched the answers for hours and decided to ask instead. And right after, I found the solution. Just in case anyone is interested in the answer. I got my solution from this answer
[Selecting data from schema based table in Postgresql using psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839085/selecting-data-from-schema-based-table-in-postgresql-using-psycopg2)

```
print(con.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT "column_name" FROM schema_name."table_name";"""))
```

This is the way to do it, with a looot of quotation marks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your framework alchemy but the correct query should be something like that:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'
```

Reference [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/information-schema.html)

Comment: how do I incorporate this to my query so I can query data from the table?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than manually quoting the identifiers in queries you can let SQLAlchemy do the work for you.

Given this table and data:

```
test# create table "Horse-Bus" (
test(#   id integer generated always as identity,
test(#   name varchar,                                                                                                       
test(#   primary key(id)                                                                                                     
test(# );
CREATE TABLE
test#
test# insert into "Horse-Bus" (name) values ('Alice'), ('Bob'), ('Carol');
INSERT 0 3
```

You can create a [Table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) object and [query](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_select.html#the-select-sql-expression-construct) it like this:

```
>>>import sqlalchemy as sa
>>> engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql:///test', echo=False, future=True)
>>> tbl = sa.Table('Horse-Bus', sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)
>>> with engine.connect() as conn:
...     rows = conn.execute(sa.select(tbl))
...     for row in rows:
...         print(row)
... 
(1, 'Alice')
(2, 'Bob')
(3, 'Carol')
>>>
```

Comment: I have to use raw sqls to query, and there's more than one table to query from. But it does seem like a sound solution, I'll try it out later.